# Search Query for Oracle SQL APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create an advance search query using oracle SQL in Oracle APEX class report.

Is there a way to insert the query line into the query when there are values in the parameter?

For example, I have a query like so:

```
select person_id, fullname from person where first_name like '%:P11_FNAME%' AND last_name like '%:P11_LNAME%'
```

is there a way to add the `first_name like '%:P11_FNAME%'` into the query when there are actual values being passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind variable syntax will not be recognised by the SQL engine if it is embedded within a string literal like `'%:P11_FNAME%'`.

You need to use string concatenation to do what you wanted:

```
select person_id, fullname from person
where first_name like '%' || :P11_FNAME || '%'
AND last_name like '%' || :P11_LNAME || '%';
```

If the user leaves search criteria blank, this will match all rows except those that have a `NULL` for the name. To make a blank search criterion match all rows, you need to add extra predicates, e.g.:

```
select person_id, fullname from person
where (first_name like '%' || :P11_FNAME || '%' or :P11_FNAME is null)
AND (last_name like '%' || :P11_LNAME || '%' or :P11_LNAME is null);
```